# aligning slides to centre with css or in flexslider.js

Tags: javascript, css, slider, alignment

I just wondered if anyone had a fix to get these slides to align vertically in the middle. I've tried `vertical-position: middle;` in CSS and other suggestions but to no avail.

[The page can be found here](http://taconstructionuk.com/dunnington.html).

Comment: Have you tried vertical align with position absolute?

Comment: Your images are taller than the slideshow area — do you want them centered and masked within the slideshow?

Comment: Hi yes, they're bigger as when clicked they popup in a lightbox. So yes masking the extra within the slider is the idea. Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use this snippet to align things vertically, since CSS's vertical-align tends to be so moody ;)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.vAlign = function(fn) {

        return this.each(

            function(i){

                var ah = $(this).height();
                var ph = $(this).parent().height();
                var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
                $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
            });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can call it like this:  $(".your-element").vAlign();

Comment: So would it be like this:
    <script src="[[++base_url]]assets/templates/taconstructionuk/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script>(function ($) {
        $.fn.vAlign = function(fn) {

            return this.each(

                function(i){

                    var ah = $(this).height();
                    var ph = $(this).parent().height();
                    var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
                    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
                });
        };
    })(jQuery);
    </script><script>$(".slides").vAlign();</script>
    <!-- Flex Slider  -->